# Drawing a Hasse Diagram

Tags: discrete-mathematics, order-theory

I am trying to draw a Hasse diagram and wanted to see if anyone can let me know if I am doing it right.

Let R = {(a,b) | a divides b} be a relation over the set {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 12}

[image]

That is what I have so far and I'm not sure if it is the right diagram.

The maximal element of R would be 12 and 5, 12 is the greatest element

The minimal element of R would be 1, it is also the least element

The least upper bound of {2} is 4.

Is this right?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 2):

The diagram looks right.

But I don't agree with "the least upper bound of $\{2\}$ is $4$". Namely, $2$ is another, smaller upper bound.

Also, under the "divides" relation, 12 and 5 are incomparable, so neither of them can be a greatest element.

Comment: So there isn't a greatest element and the least upper bound of {2} is 2?

Comment: @KarimB: Correct. In general, a one-element set always has the element itself as least upper bound as well as greatest lower bound.

Comment: Thank you so much for clearing that up!